# Tensorflow MNIST TFRecord

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

How would I go about changing the [MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) tutorial to use TFRecords instead of the odd format the tutorial downloads from the web?

I used [build_image_data.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_image_data.py) from the inception model to create my TFRecords containing 200x200 RGB images and intend to train this on a 1080Ti, but I can't find any good examples on how to load TFRecords and feed them into a convolutional neural network.

Comment: Check out [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) it has examples that show how to load data from TFRecord files and gt tensors with the data. Then it's only a matter of passing that data as input to your network instead of whatever input the network gets at the moment

Comment: @GPhilo I have my dataset available as a     "images: Images. 4D tensor of size [batch_size, FLAGS.image_size,
                                       image_size, 3].
    labels: 1-D integer Tensor of [FLAGS.batch_size].", but I don't see tf.estimator.inputs having a function to take what I loaded.

Comment: tf.estimator.inputs has convenience functions to transform data that is not already in tensor-format into something the network can take. You'll need to rewrite the `input_fn`. I'm not familiar with this high-levl API, but from the [Estimator documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) I think you need to define an `input_fn` that returns a dict `{'images':your_image_tensor, 'labels':your_label_tensor}`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing as you intend doing. I also took the same script to build image data. My code for reading the data and training it is

```
import tensorflow as tf

height = 28
width = 28

tfrecords_train_filename = 'train-00000-of-00001'
tfrecords_test_filename = 'test-00000-of-00001'


def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'image/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/colorspace': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/channels': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'image/class/text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/filename': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=''),
            'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value='')
        })

    image_buffer = features['image/encoded']
    image_label = tf.cast(features['image/class/label'], tf.int32)

    # Decode the jpeg
    with tf.name_scope('decode_jpeg', [image_buffer], None):
        # decode
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)

        # and convert to single precision data type
        image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
        image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)

    image_shape = tf.stack([height, width, 1])
    image = tf.reshape(image, image_shape)

    return image, image_label


def inputs(filename, batch_size, num_epochs):
    if not num_epochs: num_epochs = None

    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename], num_epochs=None)
        image, label = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

        # Shuffle the examples and collect them into batch_size batches.
        images, sparse_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=2,
            capacity=1000 + 3 * batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=1000)

        return images, sparse_labels

image, label = inputs(filename=tfrecords_train_filename, batch_size=200, num_epochs=None)
image = tf.reshape(image, [-1, 784])
label = tf.one_hot(label - 1, 10)

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    for i in range(1000):
        img, lbl = sess.run([image, label])
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: img, y_: lbl})

    img, lbl = sess.run([image, label])
    print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: img, y_: lbl}))

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

This is a super easy model for classifying mnist. However I think it is also an extensible answer for how to train with TFRecord files. It does not yet take into account the evaluation data, since this needs more coordination to be done.